# Java: using class function having wildcard type parameter

Tags: java, type-parameter

I get a compile error at line (B) "AlphaData cannot be converted to CAP#1 by method invocation conversion".  My work-around is to change the signature of indexOf() at line (A) to be of type Object instead of T.  However, then I lose type checking.  Further, I want line B to work if "data" were declared as type BetaData as well.  Is there a way to do what I want?

```
public class Test
{
  class AlphaData {} // base class for data

  class BetaData extends AlphaData {} // subclass for data

  abstract class BasicAdapter<T> // a generic adapter
  {
    abstract int indexOf (T item); //(A)
  }

  class BetaAdapter extends BasicAdapter<BetaData> // adapter subclass with binding
  {
    int indexOf (BetaData item) { return 0; }
  }


  BasicAdapter<? extends AlphaData> adapter = null;

  Test()
  {
    AlphaData data = null;
    int index = adapter.indexOf (data); //(B) -- compile error here
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you instantiate adapter?

Comment: The example as written would allow only one instantiation: new BetaAdapter().  However it would need to work for other subclasses of BasicAdapter as well as subclasses of BetaAdatper.

Answer (score 3):

`adapter.indexOf` cannot safely be passed an `AlphaData` because it might concretely be a `BasicAdapter<BetaData>`; although `data` could concretely be an instance of `BetaData`, it could be plain `AlphaData`, or any other unrelated subclass of `AlphaData`.

The acronym to remember is **PECS**:

- Producers `extend`
- Consumers `super`

You want `adapter` to *consume* an `AlphaData`, so you would need a `BasicAdapter<? super AlphaData>`.

Answer (score 2):

This is normal.

```
BasicAdapter<? extends AlphaData> adapter = null
```

declares that `adapter` is a `BasicAdapter` of some type that extends `AlphaData` but it could be any type, so `T = any type that extends AlphaData`. Hence, when you're calling

```
AlphaData data = null;
int index = adapter.indexOf (data); //(B) -- compile error here
```

you are giving a `AlphaData` parameter, so it doesn't comply with "something that is a `AlphaData`": it could be a `BetaData` for example.

If you want it to work for any `AlphaData`, just use:

```
BasicAdapter<AlphaData> adapter = null;
```

without using wildcards, or

```
BasicAdapter<? super AlphaData> adapter = null;
```

This will compile if `data` is a `AlphaData` or a `BetaData`.